# Can radio buttons be bound to an attached behavior in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, attachedbehaviors

In XAML, I have a set of radio buttons as:

```
<RadioButton Width="25"
             Height="25"
             Foreground="Blue"
             IsChecked="{Binding ??????, Converter={StaticResource StrokeTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter="Ellipse}"
             GroupName="StrokeTypeGroup" />
```

The purpose of each radio button of the "StylusTypeGroup" is to allow selection of either an "Ellipse" , "Line" , or "Rectangle" custom stroke, etc...

Further down in the XAML, I have a behavior tied to an InkCanvas like:

```
  <InkCanvas x:Name="MainInkCanvas"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Background="Transparent" 
             DefaultDrawingAttributes="{Binding CurrentPen.Pen}"
             EditingMode="{Binding EditingMode}">
          <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                 <b:MainInkCanvasBehavior CustomStrokeType = "{Binding???????}" />
           </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Is there any way using just the XAML code, *to bind the result of checking any one (of multiple) radio buttons **directly*** to the CustomStrokeType dependency property of the MainInkCanvasBehavior **behavior**?  Or am I forced to bind to a property on the viewmodel (as kind of a holding property)?

TIA

Comment: Your question is unclear. What type is CustomStrokeType and what are you trying to bind to?

Comment: Bind to a boolean on the viewmodel that has INotifyProperty changed implemented, ie. public bool IsButtonAChecked { ... }

Comment: @mmi CustomStrokeType has yet to be determined. My question is simply can a radio button be bound to ANY property on a behavior of another element.

Comment: @Patrick So...essentially use a viewmodel as a intermediary messenger...(i.e., no way to bind directly in XAML from the radiobuttons to a behavior on another element)??

Comment: @AlanWayne you can bind to an Element, but you have to ask yourself if you are going to get updates via the INotifyProperty changed mechanism... example, I can bind to TextBox.Text via the element name, path... but I don't think I will get updates.

Comment: @Patrick The behavior can bind easy enough: CustomStrokeType= {Binding ElementName= radiobutton, Path=IsChecked...}  However, I can't figure out how to do this the other way arround, i,e., IsChecked={binding to behavior...} That is, I can bind one-to-one, behavior to radiobutton, but not many to one as RadioButton to Behavior...if you get what I mean.:)

Comment: @AlanWayne That's what a MultiValueConverter can do, its many-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least amount of effort is to create a new property, CheckedRadioButtonID, bind that to your CustomStrokeType and use an IValueConverter to take an int and return a Stroke.  The key is that when the radio button is clicked, you also want to raise an INotifyPropertyEvent for the CheckedRadioButtonID.

```
   public int CheckedRadioButtonID 
    {
get 
{
  if(IsAChecked) return 1; 
/// ...
}
     // returns 1,2,3... (number of radio buttons you have)
    //  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public bool IsAChecked
    {
     set 
    {
     // when this is set... also raise CheckedRadioButtonID  property changed
    }
    }
```

In XAML bind to CheckedRadioButtonID and have a IValueConverter take an int and return a Stroke.

If you really want to use a MultiValueConverter it would like like this

```
                     <b:MainInkCanvasBehavior >
    <b:MainInkCanvasBehavior.CustomStrokeType>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterThatReturnsStroke}">  
                        <Binding ElementName="RadioButton1" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>  
                        <Binding ElementName="RadioButton2" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>  
                    </MultiBinding>  
    </b:MainInkCanvasBehavior.CustomStrokeType>
</b:MainInkCanvasBehavior>
```

Comment: Yep...same conclusion I've come to. I wish there was a way to bind multiple radio buttons to the same property on the behavior directly in the XAML without going through the viewmodel. You confirmed my thinking. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne I added some MultiValue stuff to my answer

Comment: Looks good! I've not used a Multibinding converter like that before. Thats new to me.  Thanks!